# R - passing variable containing column name into sum()

Tags: r, variables, sum

Let's say we've attached a data from a table containing column 'banana' with numeric values.

`colName='banana'`

Now we want the sum of that column, assuming we don't know what it's called, we only know the name is being stored in the colName variable. How do we call the sum() function? Neither does `sum(as.name(colName))` nor  `sum(as.symbol(colName))` seem to work. 
`noquotes()` doesn't work either.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but you do not know the name of the object but only the name of the column of that (unknown) object? in that case you should use `ls()` to see all object in your R working session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sample data:

```
colnm <- "squash"
df <- data.frame(squash=1:10, avocado="so good")
```

If you `attach` your `df` you could do this:

```
attach(df)
sum(get(colnm))
#[1] 55
```

This will do it without having to `attach`:

```
sum(df[colnm])
#[1] 55
```

Comment: Note: `sum(df[colnm])` did not work for me but `sum(df[ ,colnm])` did.